# Uninstalled Snaps Still Exist in /var/lib/snapd/snaps

Tags: snap, opera

There are some snap packages that I uninstalled with the command `snap remove app`. I looked in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`, and there is still an `opera_137.snap` file in there, although I removed the Opera snap (I have Opera installed as a .deb file, which is beside the point). It takes up half a Gigabyte, and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to remove it or not. In `nautilus`, the file shows up with the big Admin "X," shown below:

[image]

If I run `snap list`, Opera **does not** show up, so it is clearly not "installed."

Why is that snap package still showing up in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`? Am I able to remove it without breaking my system?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: @nobody I have uninstalled Opera a while ago and it was just recently that I realized the problem above. So yes, I probably rebooted like 20 times over the course.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this with
sudo snap remove --purge .

1. The snapshots directory still contains a snapshot for the package.
2. the seed directory still contains the package
3. The cache files still have information for the package
4. there are files in ~/snap/ and /root/snap/

Item 1: man snap revealed how to use the snap save and snap forget commands:

snap forget 2 removed it

Item 2. man snap did not reveal anything useful for removing the seed. I believe the seed file can be removed manually without causing problems.

Item 3. The cache files are binary, so it isn't easy to discern what exactly is being cached.
snap saved identified set # 2 for package-nameex

snap forget 2 removed it

Item 4. What the files are in the user directories ~/snap and /root/snap is an unanswered question, left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: RE #2: Seed snaps can be removed by stopping snap seed service and removing entries from seed configuration. 1.`sudo service snapd.seeded status` 2.`sudo service snapd.seeded stop` 3.`sudo vi /var/lib/snapd/seed/seed.yaml` and remove all entries, just leave `snaps:` at the top. 4. `sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/*.snap` to remove associated seed snaps. 5. `sudo service snapd.seeded start` 6. `sudo service snapd.seeded status`